# Detecting biometrics on Pixel 4XL fails with BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-biometric

Testing for biometrics on a Pixel 4XL (Android Q) fails returning `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE`.

I have setup face recognition

Android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

gradle dependancies

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1"
}
```

**Test code**

```
private boolean setBIOSetup() {
    BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(getActivity());
    switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
            return true; 
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No biometric hardware installed", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE: 
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Biometric hardware unavailable.", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              break; 
         case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED: 
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No biometrics enrolled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
             break;
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

On a Pixel 2XL it returns `BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS` for fingerprint biometrics
but for Pixel 4XL it returns `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

The Pixel 4 and 4 XL do not feature any finger-print sensor, but only face-unlock.

You've already filed a bug filed against the library, see issue [#146978096](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146978096)
and you should follow their suggestion to run `adb bugreport foo.zip`.

[`BiometricManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricManager) `.canAuthenticate()` at least states the three prerequisites:

> Determines if biometrics can be used, or equivalently, whether BiometricPrompt can be shown.
>
> - hardware available
> - templates enrolled
> - user-enabled

If it's indeed a bug, you'll have to wait until `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.2` was released.